# CSS Spin Animation not spinning on Safari on iOS and Mac

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, styled-components

I want to make a spinning animation on loading, the spin is perfectly working on Chrome on my Mac but on Chrome on my iPhone and on Safari Browser on iPhone and on Mac its not spinning at all.

Here is the CSS:

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid rgba(195, 195, 195, 0.6);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top-color: #636767;
  animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation:spin 1s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1s infinite linear;

    @keyframes spin {
    0%          { transform:rotate(0deg); }
    50%         { transform:rotate(180deg); }
    100%        { transform:rotate(360deg); }
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes spin {
      0%          { -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); }
      50%         { -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg); }
      100%        { -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); }
  }

  @-moz-keyframes spin {
    0%          { -moz-transform:rotate(0deg); }    
    50%         { -moz-transform:rotate(180deg); }
    100%        { -moz-transform:rotate(360deg); }
  }
}
```

I tried define the animation more described like this but it didnt help:

```
{
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

can you help me fix this?

Comment: What kind of element are you animating? Is it `block` or `inline`?

Comment: @Jax-p display:inline-block;